# Scala Play reading XML string

Tags: xml, scala

I am sending `XML(text/xml)` content-type and in Controller is getting String as

```
`AnyContentAsXml(<SomeTag>....</SomeTag>)`
```

which should be like

```
'<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><SomeTag>....</SomeTag>`
```

So how I can convert `AnyContentAsXml` to XML string?

Comment: If you look at the documentation, you can see [how to work with XML](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaXmlRequests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play has a builtin xml body parser, you can use like

```
def someendpoint = Action(parse.xml) { request =>
  val elementOpt = request.body \\ "someelement" headOption
}
```

notice that, `request.body` is a `NodeSeq` and can be used to do any xml releated thing.